# How to calculate the distance between this two buildings?

Tags: geometry

A narrow street is lined with tall buildings. An x foot long ladder is rested at the base of the building on the right side of the street and leans on the building on the left side. A y foot long ladder is rested at the base of the building on the left side of the street and leans on the building on the right side. The point where the two ladders cross is exactly c feet from the ground. How wide is the street?
[The Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjgaa.jpg)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e. its about mathematics and not Mathematica. If that's not your intenetion, please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make it explicitly about Mathematica programming. Include a minimum example of the code you are working on.

Comment: Hi, on this site, you are expected to show what effort you have made and difficulties you are facing to enable appropriate help.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456508/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-this-two-buildings]